# IRCBot send file / DCC File transfer

Tags: php, bots, irc, sendfile

I'm implementing a IRCBot to send files but can't find anything on this, has anyone ever done this?

- PHP is the language
- Symfony 2 is the framework
- IRCBotBundle https://github.com/whisller/IrcBotBundle I'm using / modifying

Looking for implementation on sending files from the IRCBot to a end user. I've seen some mention of DCC but nothing for PHP

Comment: Log files ? What are they ? You want to use DCC ? What have you tried ?

Comment: well files is what I need, log files are specific to my needs. Could you point me to some DCC Implementation with PHP and I'm exploring the options before trying anything but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IRC` is a chat protocol not a file sharing protocol, however for file sharing some client's such as mIRC use `DCC` (Direct Client to Client) to send any files.

This is acomplished using commands such as `DCC SEND <filename> <ip> <port> <file size>`

This would have to be implemented into your bot (not something IRC supports directly), therefore you would have to open a socket to their IP address and send the file in the buffer using `socket_send()`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-send.php

Comment: Way to not answer the question.

Comment: @Leigh - I disagree - the OP is asking on how to send files via IRC, from using IRC myself mIRC uses the DCC approach which would simply open a connection to the client via a socket and send the file.  What would you suggest?

Comment: The question (which is not a good question - "give me teh codez"), is asking for an implementation of DCC, not an explanation of what IRC is (or isn't). You have not provided any implementation specifics, only a  couple of short summaries of things he wasn't asking for. (in my opinion)

Comment: @leigh - My answer is not aimed at explaining what IRC is or isnt, I stated that as additional information. You must be missing the information providing to socket_send which he can use to implement a DCC command which is what the OP IS asking for.

Answer (score 1):

This PHP Bot implementation supports DCC : http://www.phpbots.org/

You either need to base your work on that one, or to read the code and cherry-pick the parts you are interested in.